# NameError: name 'exit' is not defined neo

Tags: python

I am trying to run the code, but i have an error NameError: name 'exit' is not defined

```
import neo
import numpy as np
import mne
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft

reader = neo.io.Spike2IO(<'filename'>) 
data = reader.read(lazy=False)[0].segments[0] 
SF = float(data.analogsignals[0].sampling_rate) #int(round())
arr = np.array(data.analogsignals[0][:, 0]).flatten()
info = mne.create_info(['EEG1'], sfreq=SF, ch_types=['eeg'])
raw = mne.io.RawArray(arr.reshape((1, -1)), info)
SF = round(SF)
raw.resample(SF, npad='auto')
arr = raw.get_data().flatten()
```

the error appears immediately after the execution of the line: reader = neo.io.Spike2IO('filename')

it outputs the file structure to the terminal, and then the code does not want to be executed.

I use Google Collab, but in VSCode it also doesn't work  (although before that, on another computer that I don't have access to right now, it works fine and now I wonder what the problem is (VSCode))

full text or error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ec7d748b28bf> in <module>()
      1 #
----> 2 reader = neo.io.Spike2IO(<'filename'>)
      3 data = reader.read(lazy=False)[0].segments[0] 
      4 SF = float(data.analogsignals[0].sampling_rate) #int(round())
      5 arr = np.array(data.analogsignals[0][:, 0]).flatten()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/neo/rawio/spike2rawio.py in _parse_header(self)
     66                 from pprint import pprint
     67                 pprint(chan_info)
---> 68                 exit()
     69 
     70 

NameError: name 'exit' is not defined
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide full error traceback?

Comment: What happens if you add `exit()` above the line `reader = neo.io.Spike2IO(<'filename'>) `?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the relevant library: [Neo](https://github.com/NeuralEnsemble/python-neo), especially script pointed by at error traceback (neo/rawio/spike2rawio.py) it can be seen that the code is different and there is no problematic `exit()` in it. Try updating your library to newest official version and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: i use the latest version of neo

Comment: Seems some crap got into release version of the library - open the `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/neo/rawio/spike2rawio.py` file and remove 3 lines shown by the error, I think it should help.

Comment: I deleted it, but the error did not disappear  https://pastenow.ru/98618bbd9b0df4793757dd35aa54bd20

Comment: I restarted the environment and everything worked

Comment: I've created a GitHub issue for the bug in case you want to follow what is going on: https://github.com/NeuralEnsemble/python-neo/issues/1089

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with exit. Use `sys.exit()` instead, as shown below:

```
try:
     print"Try this."
     sys.exit(0)
except SystemExit:
     pass
except:
     print"Failed."
     sys.exit(1)
```